# SQL Transaction connected with WAITFOR DELAY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I was looking through some posts but I couldn’t find similar case that could explain me if this solution is safe. I want to execute many `UPDATE` queries at once but due to server performance issues, I can run only limited number of queries at once. The solution seems to be easy by using `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'` between queries, and execute everything at once.
My transaction is going to look like this:

```
Begin tran 

UPDATE Queries

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

UPDATE Queries

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

etc.
```

After manual verification how many rows are affected, I execute `commit tran`. Are all the queries updating at once when `commit tran` is executed causing performance issue? Is `commit tran` safe for use in my case?

Comment: Depends what the "performance issues" are. If they are to do with concurrency, having the `WAITFOR` inside the transaction is probably making matters worse. Are you able to `COMMIT` these transactions in batches?

Comment: Performance issues are coming from Application Server that is using this database, it has nothing to do with concurrency. I don't want to commit them in batches because I need to manualy verify how many rows are affected by UPDATE statements.

Comment: Opening a transaction locks rows, and can cause blocking.  If you are updating 5000 or more rows, you could escalate to a full table lock!  Can you not do SELECTS before the updates to evaluate the row count??

Comment: I am using UPDATE SET WHERE statements only in my queries. I am updating only 20 statements at a time, that's my limit. I am going through this article about locking: [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598(v=sql.110).aspx) and I dont think locking is an issue in my case.